# Inserting words into a table

Tags: lua

So, i have a script where i am inputting 3 words in a string and putting them into a small table and i only need this script to print a new table i can copy and paste, so i just need to print what the table would look like this is the script currently have

```
   local tbl = {
   {1, "", 0},
   {2, "", 0},
    {3, "", 0}
   }



   local input = "i hate debugging"
   local words = {}
   x = 0
   repeat
   x = x + 1
   for i, v in ipairs(tbl) do
   if tonumber(v[1]) == x then
   for word in input:gmatch"[^ ,\r\n]+" do
               
    table.insert(words, word)

   end
   end
   end
   until x == 1
```

and the desired output should look like this

```
  {1, "i", 0},
  {2, "hate", 0},
  {3, "debugging", 0},
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How do i get the desired output i posted ive tried various ways but i dont know how to get there.

Comment: @SMEEDLE -- do you have to modify the existing `tbl`, or can you just create a new `tbl` from the input string?

Comment: yes creating a new tbl is what i need

Comment: @SMEEDLE -- you need to use `@` before a username if you want to ping someone in comments. I have added to my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear, and OP goal is not clear, but it seems that you may want something like this:

```lua
local tbl = {
  { 1, "", 0 },
  { 2, "", 0 },
  { 3, "", 0 }
}

local input = "i hate debugging"

local nextWord = input:gmatch"[^ ,\r\n]+"
for k, t in ipairs(tbl) do
  t[2] = nextWord() or ""
end

-- Display updated `tbl`
print("updated tbl")
for k, v in ipairs(tbl) do
  print(string.format('{ %d, "%s", %d },', v[1], v[2], v[3]))
end
```

`gmatch` returns an iterator, so you can just call this iterator repeatedly to get successive matches. You can loop over `tbl`, calling the iterator each time to set the string. When the iterator is out of matches it will return `nil`, so the code sets the string to `""` when the iterator is exhausted.

Program output:

```
updated tbl
{ 1, "i", 0 },
{ 2, "hate", 0 },
{ 3, "debugging", 0 },
```

### Creating A New Table From Input

OP has clarified in a comment that a new table should be created from the input. Here is a function `createWordTable` that creates and returns a fresh table from a string of words. The `printWordTable` function is just a utility function to show the contents of a word table.

```lua
function createWordTable(wordString)
  local wordTbl = {}
  local i = 1
  for w in wordString:gmatch"[^ ,\r\n]+" do
    wordTbl[i] = { i, w, 0 }
    i = i + 1
  end
  return wordTbl
end

function printWordTable(wordTbl)
  for k, v in ipairs(wordTbl) do
    print(string.format('{ %d, %s, %d }', v[1], v[2], v[3]))
  end
end
```

Sample interaction:

```
> wtbl = createWordTable("one, two, three")
> printWordTable(wtbl)
{ 1, one, 0 }
{ 2, two, 0 }
{ 3, three, 0 }
> wtbl = createWordTable("one, two, three, four, five") 
> printWordTable(wtbl)
{ 1, one, 0 }
{ 2, two, 0 }
{ 3, three, 0 }
{ 4, four, 0 }
{ 5, five, 0 }
```